# Nodejs throws error on require('socket.io')

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have nodejs on windows x64

on require('socket.io').listen(8080); or just require('socket.io'); i get this error:

```
C:\node>node applications/app.js
C:\node\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling.js:23
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({ xdomain: false });
            ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at C:\node\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling.js:23:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\
polling.js:25:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\
polling-xhr.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are somehow including the wrong `socket.io` library.  `XMLHttpRequest` is a browser object and is only available in the browser.  If you're using socket.io in node.js, you presumably want the server-side version of the library which would not be attempting to use `XMLHttpRequest`.

And, when you look into the paths names, it appears you're somehow drawing in `engine.io-client` which is not what you want.

This is the server-side module you want: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

---

If, by any chance you have the right module, but you are doing a `require()` on the client module that is for the browser, then that could also cause the problem you are seeing as that would be a mistake and should be removed.

Comment: No, it was the same version. It includes server and client module, but thanks to your answer, i'v just commented //var client = require('socket.io-client'); in socket.io and it works!

Comment: @ПавелШаталов - why did you say the error occurred when you did `require('socket.io');`?   Was that not really the case?  Anyway, I've added a piece to my answer to address what you found.

Comment: my app.js only containts require('socket.io'); And socket.io library contains require('socket.io-client'). I had to edit socket.io to prevent this error. But i still cant understand, why simple require causes this error;

Comment: @ПавелШаталов - you have something messed up in your server-side socket.io code installation if it is accidentally pulling in and using the browser library as a default and correct installation will not do that and you should not have to edit anything to stop it from doing that.  About all I can suggest is to do an NPM list to see all socket.io modules you have installed, jot down all their names, remove them all and then reinstall only the correct server-side module.

Comment: i'v downloaded https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io, look at line 10 in lib/index.js

Comment: Same problem. Works fine in Linux, but not work in windows x64.

Comment: I removed `node_modules` folder and `npm install` all packages, bug disappeared...